# Trying to add product with description via REST

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

Apologies if this is a silly question, I'm sure it must be but I just can't seem to figure out how you are supposed to add a product's description via REST.

The REST API docs at http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_20.html under the `catalogProductRepositoryV1` list all the the available fields but description is not there.

Can someone advise which resource the product's description is managed through?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to add `custom_attributes`:

```
$productData = [
        'attribute_set_id'  => 4,
        "type_id": "simple",
        "sku": "test-SKU",
        "name": "Test",
        "price": 100,
        "status": 1,
        'custom_attributes' => [
                ['attribute_code' => 'description', 'value' => 'Test Description' ],
                ['attribute_code' => 'short_description', 'value' => 'Test Short Description' ],
            ]
    ];
```

Payload:

```
{
    "product": {
        "attribute_set_id": 4,
        "type_id": "simple",
        "sku": "test-SKU",
        "name": "Test",
        "price": 100,
        "status": 1,
        "custom_attributes": {
            "description": "Test Description",
            "short_description": "Test Short Description"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe that your JSON Payload field `custom_attributes` is wrong. It should possibly be `"custom_attributes": [ {"attribute_code":"description","value":"Test Description",} , "attribute_code":"short_description","value":"Test Short Description"} ]`.

Comment: @Khoa TruongDinh How to add selected attributes label in product rest API.

Like ['attribute_code' => 'description', 'value' => 'Test Description', 'label' => 'Description' ],

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/287627/magento-2-rest-api-products-custom-attributes-add-selected-attribute-value-l