# Magento2 REST Update custom attributes

Tags: magento2, api, upgrade, rest-api, custom-attributes

**How can I update the custom attributes such as description?**
The following code properly update price and product name, but not custom attributes (unchanged). The new product is created properly with custom attributes, the problem is while updating.

[image: magento2 REST Update custom attributes]

[image: magento2 REST Update custom attributes]

Comment: Hi guys, in your case,I think you need do again: php bin/magento upgrade

Comment: Hi guys, I think you give us the code or config of attribute for custom_attributes. To we check again.

Comment: Have you check any answer? need your comments.

Answer (score 19):

To create product, we can use:

- *POST*: **/V1/products**

For updating:

- *PUT*: **/V1/products/{sku}**

In your case, your code should be:

```
$productData = [
        'attribute_set_id'  => 4,
        "type_id": "simple",
        "sku": "test-SKU",
        "name": "Test",
        "price": 100,
        "status": 1,
        'custom_attributes' => [
                ['attribute_code' => 'description', 'value' => 'Test Description' ],
                ['attribute_code' => 'short_description', 'value' => 'Test Short Description' ],
            ]
    ];
```

The JSON body:

```
 {
  "product": {
    "sku": "test-SKU",
    "name": "Test",
    "attribute_set_id": 4,
    "price": 100,
    "status": 1,
    "custom_attributes": [
      {
        "attribute_code": "description",
        "value": "Test Description"
      },
      {
        "attribute_code": "short_description",
        "value": "Test Short Description"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

There is an answer here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/135607/33057

Comment: Hi , @Khoa you need to format array to json string, because he used REST and by REST tool.

Comment: @MagentoOdoo.com Thanks! I updated my answer.

Comment: @Khoa TruongDinh How to add selected attributes label in product rest API.

Like ['attribute_code' => 'description', 'value' => 'Test Description', 'label' => 'Description' ],

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/287627/magento-2-rest-api-products-custom-attributes-add-selected-attribute-value-l

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh 

How to pass label in /V1/products/{sku} 'attribute_code' => 'color', 'value' => '54', 'label' => 'Blue'

 Let me know if you have idea. Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/287627/magento-2-rest-api-products-custom-attributes-add-selected-attribute-value-l

Answer (score 3):

Try to pass your custom attributes within array like:

```
'custom_attributes' => array(
     '0' => array(
          'attribute_code' => 'my_custom_attribute_code',
          'value' => 'my_custom_attribute_value'
      )
      ...
)
```

Comment: How to pass label in /V1/products/{sku}
'attribute_code' => 'color',
'value' => '54',
'label' => 'Blue'

Let me know if you have idea. Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/287627/magento-2-rest-api-products-custom-attributes-add-selected-attribute-value-l