# How to update sku code using Rest API in Magento 2?

Tags: product, rest-api

I want to update sku using Rest API in magento 2
Call:

> PUT /rest/V1/products/{sku}

```
Request:
{
"product": {
"sku": "modified.sku",
"name": "modified name"
}
}
```

Result:
The name has changed, but the sku is the same. How can I change the product sku?

Comment: There is some possible solutions available. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/164278/update-product-using-rest-api-in-magento-2

Answer (score 1):

SKU is a unique key for products. It can't be changed via the API.

Comment: I initially upvoted this answer but it turns out it’s wrong, as you can verify by using the code in mydons’ answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can update the SKU using the below request format. Since there is a bug in magento which doesn't update the new values for some store views. You can use the below Request URL and Request JSON.

PUT: rest/**all**/V1/products/{sku}.

```
{
  "saveOptions": "true",
  "product": {
    "id": 1,
    "sku": "modified.sku",
    "name": "modified.name",
    "attribute_set_id": your_attribute_set_id,
    "price": 34,
    "status": 1,
    "visibility": 4,
    "type_id": "simple"
   }
 }
```

Comment: The key is to add "id" and "saveOptions". It doesn't work when "saveOptions" is not added but works even if it's set true or false!